# Dojo Dijit.Form.isValid() when adding fields by DOM Manipulation

Tags: forms, validation, dojo, dom-manipulation

I have a dijit.Form element on my page with two fields, name and comments where have just a require=true. Comments don't have validation rules.
If i submit the form and check if it is valid it works.

My problem occurs when i add fields name="columns" with DOM Manipulation. It validate when i'm typing, it shows that This field is required, but when i got my dijit.Form.isValid() it says that don't have errors, but it have, and it is showing me.

What is happening? Why don't validate when i submit it and use the isValid()?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 1):

You must call `form.connectChildren` if you add widgets to the form after startup.

See http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/form/Form/connectChildren